# how to display max, min, median, and average from tableau

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

on that picture, that is user_id and the right side are the frequency of transaction for each users,

how to display the minimum, max, median, and average for the frequency transaction of this users?

what calculation do i need to made for this kind of problems?

so the median max min and average will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article about [Window Functions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.htm)

For the min use WINDOW_MIN(COUNTD([Order Id]))

For the max use WINDOW_MAX, etc