# how to combine all of the results of count for every max, min, median, average

Tags: tableau-api, aggregation, summary, level-of-detail

this is the continous from my question from here [how to display max, min, median, and average from tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816739/how-to-display-max-min-median-and-average-from-tableau/64818135#64818135)

i have data like this
[image]

on that picture, that is user_id and the right side are the frequency of transaction for each users

so based on the solution, i've used window function, and used min with this

```
WINDOW_MIN(COUNTD([Order Id]), FIRST(), LAST())
```

max with this

```
WINDOW_MAX(COUNTD([Order Id]), FIRST(), LAST())
```

median with this

```
WINDOW_MEDIAN(COUNTD([Order Id]), FIRST(), LAST())
```

how to combine the results so the results can become like this (this is on my dashboard made with another software) on my worksheet, is it possible?

[image: EXPECTED RESULTS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show all these on your dashboard as a reference, why not show these in **annotation**.  Include all four in details mark card.  Right click on chart area -> include annotation -> include all four as desired.

EDIT:

Another method:  In your view wherein a 'frequency' (`COUNTD(USER_ID)`) field has been added to sheet/view, right click in sheet area and check `summary` .  Your desired calculations will be added automatically.

[image]

You can also change 'stats' to be displayed here by clicking on summary card.

Comment: lets say i already made that 4 calculations, to put all of these in my workbook (not my dashboard),  just put annotation?

Comment: Yes, in any sheet, pull all four in `details` then include them in annotation or tooltip.

Comment: i already put in the details, but how to make to annotation