# how to display all of the MIN, MAX, AVERAGE, AND MEDIAN from the results

Tags: tableau-api

i have a table like this

```
order_id | user_id | createdAt | transaction_amount
```

order_id as the id of the transaction, user_id as the user, createdAt as the dates, and transaction_amount is the transaction of each id order.

so this is the continue from this question [how to display max, min, median, and average from tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816739/how-to-display-max-min-median-and-average-from-tableau?rq=1)

[image]

on that picture, that is user_id and the right side are the frequency of transaction for each users. there's 3139 data.

so based on that solution i've made max min average and median from window calculation like this

for max `WINDOW_MAX(COUNTD([Order Id]), FIRST(), LAST())`
min `WINDOW_MIN(COUNTD([Order Id]), FIRST(), LAST())`
avg `WINDOW_AVERAGE(COUNTD([Order Id]), FIRST(), LAST())`
median `WINDOW_MEDIAN(COUNTD([Order Id]), FIRST(), LAST())`

so i put results for calculation on columns and rows are users_id [image]

what i want is, how to convert that numbers into like this [image]

so the min value(1), max value(12), average value (1.72), and median(1) value are only appears once, not appear many and confusing.

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample data/sheet?  I'll show you in a moment

Comment: ok wait let me edited it

Comment: its done, i put the structure of my table

Comment: okay, basically i want to put median value, min, max, and average value from the users who match with the filter that  has been made

Comment: The filters which you want to be calculated prior to calculation of these LODs, the same should be added to context by right clicking these. Else your filters will be applied after calculation of Max/Min etc.

Comment: What is the level of detail of your data? That is, what fields uniquely identify a row of data? Do you ever have more than one data row with the same order Id? If order Id is unique, then you can simplify your solution quite a bit and also improve performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposed solution.  Since `window` functions work in specific context, I propose use of LOD for these calculations.(*Context is already FIXED in all LOD calculations and therefore these are independent of sheet's view context*)

**Step-1** Make four Calculated fields as

1. `Max Frequency` as

```
Max({FIXED [User]:COUNTD([order_id])})
```

2. 'Min Frequency` as

```
Min({FIXED [User]:COUNTD([order_id])})
```

3. Average Freq as

```
AVG({FIXED [User]:COUNTD([order_id])})
```

4. Median Frequency as

```
MEDIAN({FIXED [User]:COUNTD([order_id])})
```

Add all four to crosstab view as desired.  Sample data used-

```
user    trans date  order_id
user1   02-12-2019  1
user1   02-01-2020  2
user2   03-01-2020  3
user3   03-12-2019  4
user3   04-12-2019  5
user4   01-02-2020  6
user4   02-02-2020  7
user5   02-01-2020  8
user5   03-01-2020  9
user1   03-02-2020  10
user1   03-03-2020  11
user3   03-01-2020  12
user3   03-02-2020  13
user1   04-02-2020  14
```

Desired view screenshot

[image]

I think this solves your problem.  Good luck.

Comment: how about the filters for my user? is it can be applicable when i insert the filter?

Comment: Add filters to context, so that these are calculated before calculation of Max/Min, etc.

Comment: why the results different? average 12 (its should be 1.72),  max 219 (its should be 12) , min 2 (its should be 1)